# Why does my App crash, when a Button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, button, crash

I'm currently trying to program my first Android App.
It's supposed to be a Sudoku solver, but I'm not that far yet.
I kind of got stuck, because the App crashes when I try to click a Button.
The only Button that has an `onClick` function by now is `grid_11`, so I cut out the rest which isn't important.
I hope someone can tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

```
package com.example.sudokusolver;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button grid_11;

SeekBar seekBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    grid_11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.grid_11);
    seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    grid_11.setOnClickListener(this);


}


boolean solved = false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

   if (solved == false){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.grid_11:
                grid_11.setText(seekBar.getProgress());

       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: Add error log and complete your switch block by adding break for each case and add a default case with break statement too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code

**grid_11.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));**

You can not set integer value into Button or Textview directly , you must to convert into String format.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was about to give it up and it would have been so easy.